# Integrate a third-party SDK to my project

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake, sdk

I am developing a project in C++ and compiling the whole project using CMAKE. 
I am currently trying to use a new camera which comes with its own SDK, which I installed independently (e-con Systems [TARA SDK](https://github.com/econsystems/tara-cpu-sdk)).

The only problem is that my project compiles using CMake 3.1 whilst the SDK is built using several makefiles in the SDK.

Should I modify my project CMakeLists.txt and how ? Or should I just include in the project the source files and generate new CMake files ?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you don't need to rebuild a third-party library every time. Hence, you can use their makefiles to produce what is known as [`IMPORTED`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_library.html#imported-libraries) library in CMake-speak. You can prebuild few flavors of the SDK libraries, e.g. release/debug, and import the relevant flavor into your CMake build.

In the worst case, you can modify your `CMakeLists.txt` to run **make** from CMake, but it's usually not necessary.